# Inets http client + authorization

Tags: http, erlang, authorization, inets

How should I specify user/password for client authorization in http request made by httpc:request() function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For digest, you'll need to do the same thing as basic but more so.  Generally you'll hit the page without auth, get the "WWW-Authenticate" header info, then use the realm and nonce there to generate your "Authorization" header.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication has a decent example at the bottom.

Generally, HTTPS + Basic is sufficient, if not better, for most use cases.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think `httpc` module provides facility for that.
Nevertheless it isn't hard to implement (if we are talking about Basic Authentification). After all it's just an additional request header with 'user:password' pair Base64 encoded.
For example [Tsung's ts_http_common module](http://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/src/tsung/ts_http_common.erl) does it.

For instance, here is how you can run HTTP PUT request with basic authentication:

```
auth_header(User, Pass) ->
    Encoded = base64:encode_to_string(lists:append([User,":",Pass])),
    {"Authorization","Basic " ++ Encoded}.

put_request(Url, User, Pass, Body) ->
    ContentType = "text/json",
    Headers = [auth_header(User, Pass), {"Content-Type",ContentType}],
    Options = [{body_format,binary}],
    httpc:request(put, {Url, Headers, ContentType, Body}, [], Options).
```

Comment: Thx, it does the job. What about digest? It seems that inets doesn't support it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I see in doc that HTTPOptions holds pass and user:

```
HTTPOptions = http_options()
http_options() = [http_option()]
http_option() = {timeout, timeout()} | {connect_timeout, timeout()} | {ssl, ssloptions()} | {ossl, ssloptions()} | {essl, ssloptions()} | {autoredirect, boolean()} | {proxy_auth, {userstring(), passwordstring()}} | {version, http_version()} | {relaxed, boolean()} | {url_encode, boolean()}
```

documentation: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-5

Comment: You are probably talking about proxy authorization, which is specified by a property {proxy_auth, {userstring(), passwordstring()}}. Nevertheless it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ibrowse, that supports and I am have been using that! https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse